# What could cause the Math.tan to not work?

Tags: java, math

My problem is simple. As you might now, tan(45) equals 1. When I use Math.tan(45) though, it outputs 1.6197751905438615.

I don't know if it helps, but this is the code I used:

```
double angle = Math.tan(45);
```

Any ideas why it's not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to `Math.tan` is an angle in *radians*. (This is mentioned in [the Javadoc for that method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#tan-double-).) You're giving it an angle in *degrees*.

To fix this, you can convert the angle from degrees to radians by using `Math.toRadians` (which multiplies by *π*/180):

```
double angle = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(45));
```

Note that, due to limitations of precision (both of representation and of calculation), this won't be *exactly* 1; on my machine it comes out to about 0.9999999999999998889776975.

Comment: It is probably better to use `Math.toRadians` for the conversion.

Comment: @LorisSecuro: Oh, cool! I was not aware of that method. I'll edit. :-)

Comment: Thanks for answering the question and thanks for making me look like an Idiot.

Comment: @Geniass69: Sorry, I wasn't trying to make you look like an idiot. :-/ We've all made mistakes where we assume that an API works the way that we need instead of the way that it does.